# How to block all users not containing a pattern?

Tags: 8, drush

I'm trying to block all users except ones with a specific role, and would love to use something like: `drush user:block !roadie`.

Comment: Maybe take https://github.com/richardbporter/drush-users-commands and its `drush user:toggle` command as a starting point.

Comment: @leymannx Thanks, that's a great starting point!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest use [drush block](https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/user/user:block/)

```
drush ublk $(drush sqlq 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ufd.name) FROM users u join user__roles ur on  u.uid = ur.entity_id  join users_field_data ufd on ufd.uid = u.uid where ur.roles_target_id ="YOUR_ROLE_MACHINENAME" and ufd.name like "%PATTERN%"')
```

before that make sure the query is correct and it respond what you want by

```
drush sqlq 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ufd.name) FROM users u join user__roles ur on  u.uid = ur.entity_id  join users_field_data ufd on ufd.uid = u.uid where ur.roles_target_id ="YOUR_ROLE_MACHINENAME" and ufd.name like "%PATTERN%"
```

and finally, make sure they are blocked by checking "User status" column of the result of the following command

```
drush uinf $(drush sqlq 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ufd.name) FROM users u join user__roles ur on  u.uid = ur.entity_id  join users_field_data ufd on ufd.uid = u.uid where ur.roles_target_id ="YOUR_ROLE_MACHINENAME" and ufd.name like "%PATTERN%"')
```

**PS**:

- YOUR_ROLE_MACHINENAME: change it with your desired role.
- PATTERN: you can use MySQL [LIKE statement](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/like.php)